# How come I can't access public properties or user set controls in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I grew up on VB.Net.  From there, in a routine, I could instantiate a form, and access controls that I had put on that form, like a textbox.  Further, after hiding the form, I could read public properties that got set on the form.  I am trying to do this in C# and according to the intellisense, neither is accessible.

so, in Form 1, for example I say

```
Form f = new MyOtherForm();
```

from there, f only returns things like Text, or Tag.....I can't see any controls on f to set them.

Further, MyOtherForm has a public property called MyResult.  After a show dialog, in VB.Net, I could, from the calling form, access 
    f.MyResult

In C#, I cannot.

Can someone help me understand how it works in C#?

Comment: You're treating your form as a plain ol' `Form`, which has none of these properties that you've added. Change the declaration to `MyOtherForm f = new MyOtherForm();` to tell the compiler that you really want `f` to be treated like a `MyOtherForm`, not just an empty `Form`.

Comment: Adding to what @GlorinOakenfoot mentioned, turn `Option Strict On`... things like this would be easier to catch. Otherwise you are relying on the compiler to cast it if it can...

Comment: `f.Controls` contains references to all the controls in `MyOtherForm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the properties of MyOtherForm, you should declare the form as MyOtherForm:

```
MyOtherForm f = new MyOtherForm();
```

Beside that, you should also check if the property you are looking for is set as `public`.

Comment: @ebick this answer is the correct method as it gives you the actual class not a base class MyOtherForm may have more objects than the base object (ie the controls you add) just like creating a class  that is derived from another (inherits - notice your form Inherits ) - you do not call the base class. to access members on the inherited class - they do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, learn and love the [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword.

The implicit typing that this introduces allows for you to not have to worry about getting the correct type when declaring a variable. In your case, you know exactly what you're setting it to, so it isn't a huge deal. However, when you're getting results from methods, or LINQ calls, this provides a huge benefit.

Bear in mind, this isn't like the `var` keyword in JavaScript. Your variable still has the correct type, only you don't have to set it explicitly.